# should i enable OSPF on core switch or on Edge switch?

Tags: ospf

is there any downside enable OSPF on a core switch ? we have remote office connecting back to the HQ , just wondering i should connect to branch with OSPF on a Edge switch or a Core switch

Answer (score -1):

You should use the three layer-model.
If it's a large remote office you may connect it til core, if not you should connect it to a distribution switch at the HQ.

You must have OSPF (or the same routing protocol) on both routers that are going to connect to each other.